# Getting error on method call telephony.sendSms for the telephony dependency

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, sms, telephony

I am getting the  error below while using telephony dependency for SMS in flutter, due to the dependency not

supporting sendSms method. all other method are working perfectly.

`PlatformException(failed_to_fetch_sms, Flutter Telephony: Error getting SmsManager, null, null)`

is there any solution for this error? if yes , can I implement the change in kotlin file.

Comment: same issue any solution?